# How can i correct displaced column names in pnadas?

Tags: python, pandas

My problem is the displacement of column names in my data frame after set the column  `B` column as `index`.

### What I had:

```
         A              B       C
11  6260063207400   1999-02-15  1
22  6260063207400   1999-02-18  2
29  6260063207400   1999-02-20  2
61  6260063207400   1999-02-27  2
```

### What I have:

```
            B
    A       
1999-02-15  1
1999-02-18  2
1999-02-20  2
1999-02-27  2
1999-02-28  2
```

### What I would:

```
            
    A       B
1999-02-15  1
1999-02-18  2
1999-02-20  2
1999-02-27  2
1999-02-28  2
```

Comment: Look like a `df.reset_index()` is all you need

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
df = df.reset_index()
```